# how to Uncheck Checkbox.Group in Antd React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd, ant-design-pro

I have the following Code using https://ant.design/components/checkbox/, and Trying to uncheck when a checkbox has been checked. 
I don't want to check all if button is click, just Uncheck all or the one checkbox selected.

```html
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            checked: true,
        }
        this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
    }


    onChange(value) {
        this.props.onChangeSession(value)
    }

    onChangeBox = e => {
        this.setState({
            checked: e.target.checked,
        });
    };

    unChecked = () => {
        this.props.onChangeSession([])
        this.setState({
            checked: false
        });
    };


    render () {
        const {
            data,
        } = this.props
        return  (
            <div>
                <Button type="primary" size="small" onClick={this.unChecked}>
                   Uncheck
                </Button>
                <Checkbox.Group 
                    style={{ width: '100%' }} 
                    onChange={this.onChange}>
                    <div>
                        <div className="filter-subhead">Track</div>

                        {data.map(i => 
                            <div className="filter-item">
                                <Checkbox
                                checked={this.state.checked}
                                onChange={this.onChangeBox}
                                value={i}>{i}</Checkbox>
                            </div>
                        )}                     
                    </div>
                </Checkbox.Group> 
            </div>

        )
    }
```

Any help will be appreciate!

Answer (score 5):

[Working Link](https://codesandbox.io/embed/antd-reproduction-template-tqhqt)

The toggle on the checkbox wasn't working due to `Checkbox.Group`, you can simply use `Checkbox`

---

### Regarding Checkbox State:

You can't have a single `state` for all the checkboxes, so you will need to have an array of `bool` which will serve as the state for each checkbox item.

In the example, I have initialized checkbox state on `componentDidMount` and it creates an array (`[false,false,false,...]`) and the exact same thing is used for resetting on `Uncheck`. (*Possibility of refactoring in my code*)

### User assigned state will decide whether to check the checkbox or not.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Button, Checkbox } from "antd";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import "./index.css";

let data = [3423, 3231, 334234, 55345, 65446, 45237];

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      checkboxArray: []
    };
    // this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    let createEmptyArray = new Array(data.length).fill(false);
    this.setState({ checkboxArray: createEmptyArray });
  }

  onChange(e) {
    console.log(e.target);
  }

  onChangeBox = (e, i) => {
    let checkBoxCurrentState = this.state.checkboxArray;
    checkBoxCurrentState[i] = !checkBoxCurrentState[i];
    this.setState({
      checkboxArray: checkBoxCurrentState
    });
  };

  unChecked = e => {
    let resetArray = new Array(data.length).fill(false);
    this.setState({
      checkboxArray: resetArray
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { data } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <Button type="primary" size="small" onClick={this.unChecked}>
          Uncheck
        </Button>

        <div>
          <div className="filter-subhead">Track</div>
          {data.map((i, index) => (
            <div className="filter-item">
              <Checkbox
                checked={this.state.checkboxArray[index] ? true : false}
                onChange={e => this.onChangeBox(e, index)}
                value={index}
              >
                {JSON.stringify(this.state.checkboxArray[index])}
              </Checkbox>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
        {JSON.stringify(this.state.checkboxArray)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App data={data} />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Simple copy and paste the above code and add props where required.

And if you want to user `Checkbox.Group`, will need to update the onChange method of `CheckBox.Group`

```js
let data = ['Apple', 'Pancakes', 'Butter', 'Tea', 'Coffee'];
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      checkboxArray: []
    };
    // this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    let createEmptyArray = new Array(this.props.data.length).fill(false);
    this.setState({ checkboxArray: createEmptyArray });
  }

  onChangeBox = (e, i) => {
    let checkBoxCurrentState = this.state.checkboxArray;
    checkBoxCurrentState[i] = !checkBoxCurrentState[i];
    this.setState({
      checkboxArray: checkBoxCurrentState
    });
  };

  unChecked = () => {
    let resetArray = new Array(data.length).fill(false);
    this.setState({
      checkboxArray: resetArray
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { data } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.unChecked}>Clear All</button>
        {this.props.data.map((single, index) => (
          <div>
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              id={index}
              name="scales"
              checked={this.state.checkboxArray[index]}
              onChange={e => this.onChangeBox(e, index)}
            />
            <label for={index}>{single}</label>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App data={data} />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Yeah Thats exactly the issue I'm facing. I know I can access e.target.checked through onChangeBox, but still not sure how to set false to checked. Using only react could be a good option. I still want to figure out how to do it using antd though. Thanks @DhavalJardosh !

Comment: @Mandoxsy, check my edit, have removed the `Checkbox.Group` and everything works fine, you should probably go with that approach.

Comment: This is great! yeah I see that checked works fine if we remove checkbox.group. The reason I'm using checkbox.group is because I have more than one <checkbox/> with different values, and have to pass and array of all values selected in order to filter it later. Could I still use this approach and add the values selected to an array in order to send all values selected?

Comment: I'm not sure, but you can give it a try and we can definitely resolve if there are any issues.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to use a `map` to dynamically generate the checkboxes, using state to keep track of checked value will be tricky. You should not do this.

What you should do is not include the `checked` prop at all in the component.

```
<Checkbox
    onChange={this.onChangeBox}
    value={i}>{i}
</Checkbox>
```

The checkbox should still check even if you do not include the checked prop. It's a little strange, I know.

Instead just pass the value into the onChangeBox function and handle all your logic there and set a state value on change.

I just tested it out and it works.

Comment: Thanks @NicholasPorter! I see what you mean about not including checked. I can still see checked in onChangeBox -> e.target.checked. I'm still not sure how to set e.target.checked to false to all checkbox when I trigger `toggleChecked()`. will you be able to help ? Thanks!